# Space between title sections and subsections in Table of Content (Beamer)

Tags: beamer

Does anyone know how can I increase the space between the titles of sections and subsections in the Table of Content? Here is my current Table of Content.

[image]

To be more clear, what I am looking for is to increase the space between sections "Literature review", "Hypotheses",...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick hack, you could add a bit of additional space before the `subsection in toc` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\addtobeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\vskip0.5cm}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
    
\section{sec}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\subsection{sub a}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\subsection{sub b}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```